# Javascript setting / replacing source src="" on html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

In my HTML for each source I wanted to use javascript to insert the correct video to the matching source as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var 1_video = '1.mp4';
var 2_video = '1.webm';
var 3_video = '1.ogv';
</script>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
<source src="" type="video/mp4" />
<!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
<source src="" type="video/webm" />
<!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
<source src="" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

All the examples I find keeping using jquery and I don't want to use jquery or any external library.

What is the best way to do this.
I would do something like this but I want to achieve this without using HTML id="idname" tags on my video and source element.

```
document.getElementById('video').src = 1_video;
```

Thanks for reading and any help / guidance that can be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try to select an object with "video" id so try to add id to your sources:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
<source src="" id="source-mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
<source src="" id="source-webm" type="video/webm" />
<!-- Ogg/Vorbis for older Firefox and Opera versions -->
<source src="" id="source-ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

```css
document.getElementById('source-mp4').src = 1_video;
document.getElementById('source-webm').src = 2_video;
document.getElementById('source-ogg').src = 2_video;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example instead of matching by ID is it possible to match by type="video/mp4" ?

Comment: yes i think u can do it but that will be unfit with native js, jquery will simplify your job with the css selector as :$('[type="video/mp4"]')

Comment: `1_video` is an invalid JS variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You could could have a video container, and every time you selected a new video, you could create a new element inside the container and destroy the old by using removeChild

```
    /*Destroy current element inside the container*/
     container.removeChild(element);

    /*Create new element in the container*/
     var element  = container.createElement("VIDEO");
     element.src = XYZ-video;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you gave the video an id say equal to "webVideo" or something, you could get the id, then use query selector to target the source tag within that id.

```
var videoSource = document.getElementById("webVideo").querySelector("source");
videoSource[0].src = "1_video";
```

Then use the videoSource[0] for mp4 videoSource[1] for webm and [2] for ogg